# What is a Renowned Word™?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Renowned Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Renowned Word™ | Not Renowned Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| land | sea |
| con | pro |
| Web | World |
| At | On |
| Kit | Kat |
| Kind | Hate |
| Try | Do |
| ton | gram |
| ham | pork |
| fill | empty |
| ark | noah |
| bob | name |

Here is a CSV version:

```
Renowned Words™,Not Renowned Words™
land,sea
con,pro
Web,World
At,On
Kit,Kat
Kind,Hate
Try,Do
ton,gram
ham,pork
fill,empty
ark,noah
bob,name
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Renowned Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are the only examples of Renowned Words™; I would say the chances of more existing is close to zero (for now).

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether the capitalization is essential?

Comment: Yes @GarethMcCaughan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Renowned Words™ are ones which are found in the

> usernames of askers of PSE questions which are on the first page of 15 of most highly voted questions - they also [have > 100 votes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1&sort=votes) .
>
>   Alconja has asked 4 of these so there is room for other users  - at the moment Beastly Gerbil's question at 104 votes would need to gain more to be on this page's current 107 vote minimum.

They are the following

> land - Roland for *'A short, brutal riddle'*
>  con - Alconja for *'This is important. I need you to listen…'* + three more!
>  Web - James Webster for *'Is this Tetris puzzle solvable?'*
>  At - BaSzAt for *'Game of Life: Kill the Sun'*
>  Kit - Khale_Kitha for *'Lock your computer when you walk away!'*
>  Kind - Travis Kindred for *'Internship Available! ...'*
>  Try - Tryth for *'Merlin and Hermes: Mysterious Lines'*
>  ton - dwjohnston - for *'In the 100 blue eyes problem - why is the oracle necessary?'*
>  ham - John Meacham for *'A double-agent with a conundrum'*
>  filler - stacksfiller for *'A puzzle in 140 characters'*
>  ark - MattClarke for *'Chaos and Order: a visual puzzle in stained glass'*
>   bob - ʇolɐǝz ǝɥʇ qoq for *'How can 64 = 65?'*  with 107 votes at time of writing
>
>  Title - These are renowned or highly praised questions.

Comment: Excellent! I suspect this is the right answer, but wouldn't there be a whole load more as the choice in each case seems arbitrary. Also, in reference to 'On', this answer addresses the comment by @GarethMcCaughan.

Comment: Impressive. (But I personally dislike this sort of inside-PSE-trivia question...)

Comment: @Arth All the questions in the second page already have answers, so I reckon it would be hard for them to gain upvotes to get to the first page :)

Comment: @JFox Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm not talking about new question posers, I'm talking about the multiple words for each entry that weren't displayed.. for example 'Web' could be swapped out for 'Jam' or 'me'.  Also I'd suggest that the last word 'bob' is arguably incorrect.